# Truffle Migrate for metacoin truffle box example failing

Tags: private-blockchain, truffle-migration

truffle migrate

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\ConvertLib.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\blockchain_projects\truffle_projects\metacoin\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.12+commit.7709ece9.Emscripten.clang

> Something went wrong while attempting to connect to the network. Check your network configuration.

Could not connect to your Ethereum client with the following parameters:
    - host       > 127.0.0.1
    - port       > 7545
    - network_id > *
Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle-config.js)

Truffle v5.1.0 (core: 5.1.0)
Node v10.16.3
```

Already ran ganache-cli

Answer (score 1):

I was using ganache-cli, which listens on port 8545, the solution was to update the truffle-config.js file accordingly:

```
module.exports = {
  // Uncommenting the defaults below 
  // provides for an easier quick-start with Ganache.
  // You can also follow this format for other networks;
  // see <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // for more details on how to specify configuration options!
  //
  networks: {
   development: {
     host: "127.0.0.1",
     port: 8545,  
     network_id: "*"
   },

   test: {
     host: "127.0.0.1",
     port: 7545,
     network_id: "*"
   }
  }

};
```

Then specify the network to be used with the --network flag:

```
truffle migrate --network development
```

Comment: I am getting the same error but this solution did not helped me

Comment: @DeepakBhavsar Can you post your issue? Error message and everything. Because that should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to run **ganache-cli** in the terminal. (if you doesn't have ganache CLI then firstly install it by running this command **npm install -g ganache-cli**)
After this command, you will be able to run **truffle migrate**.

this will work.